# Is it possible to assign multiple ruleflow-groups to a rule?

Tags: drools, jbpm

I would like to setup a rule to have more than one rule flow group. The reason for this is that I will have different BPMN processes which will take different subset of rules depending on their rule flow group. For example,

```
rule "Test 1" ruleflow-group "A" ruleflow-group "B"
when
    // Condition
then
    // Action
end

rule "Test 2" ruleflow-group "A"
when
    // Condition
then
    // Action
end

BPMN Process 1 is linked to ruleflow-group A, so it should run rules Test 1 and Test 2.
BPMN Process 2 is linked to ruleflow-group B, so it should run rule Test 2 only.
```

When I write rules as above, the compiler does not complain. However, when running BPMN Process 1, it only runs rule Test 2. When running BPMN Process 2, it only runs rule Test 1.

Answer (score 1):

`Rule` class definition in jboss drools [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.drools/drools-core/6.0.1.Final/org/drools/core/rule/Rule.java?av=f) has a single String field for ruleflow-group attribute. So it is not possible for one rule to have multiple ruleflow groups.

```
public void setRuleFlowGroup(final String ruleFlowGroup) {
    this.ruleFlowGroup = ruleFlowGroup;
}
```

Alternatively you can use control facts to group your rules.

```
rule 1
when
   Controller(group in ("group1", "group2"))
then
   ...
```

Comment: Yes, that's what my experiments show as well. Any idea why there is this limitation? Having this feature would make designing BPMN processes more flexible i.e. multiple BPMN processes for different rule groups.

Comment: Possibly for the simplicitys sake. You can use control facts to group your rules instead.

Comment: Could you give an example please?